# R/Bayes: Why is a wildly different prior not affecting the posterior in bayesglm{arm}?

Tags: r, bayesian

I am trying to see how different priors affect the posterior estimates in `bayesglm{arm}`. But no matter what the prior is, why is the posterior hardly changing?

```
library(Zelig); data(turnout) #Using the "turnout" data from the "Zelig" package

library(arm) #Loading the "arm" package
model.1 = bayesglm(vote ~ race + age, family=binomial(link=logit),
                   prior.df=1, prior.scale=2.5,
                   data=turnout) #This is the default specificication with a weakly informative prior
```

summary(model.1) yields:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 0.042320   0.176567   0.240  0.81058    
racewhite   0.641959   0.134136   4.786  1.7e-06 ***
age         0.011222   0.003046   3.683  0.00023 ***
```

Now compare this to:

```
model.2 = bayesglm(vote ~ race + age, family=binomial(link=logit),
                   prior.df=1, prior.scale=2.5, prior.mean=c(-100,0), #Specifying a crazy prior
                   data=turnout)
```

Summary(model.2) yields:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 0.039891   0.176720   0.226 0.821410    
racewhite   0.645076   0.134465   4.797 1.61e-06 ***
age         0.011219   0.003047   3.682 0.000231 ***
```

What's going on here? Surely a prior which is so different would influence the maximum likelihood estimates enough to sharply change the posterior?

Comment: what is your sample size? I'm not familiar with this `R` package but the prior becomes less and less important as the sample size increases - [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30387/what-is-the-relationship-between-sample-size-and-the-influence-of-prior-on-poste) is a question and two answers related to that.

Comment: Your data has 2000 points. If the data has high precision and large N this is what I would expect. If you sample the data down to just 50 observations, the estimates change more with different priors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second prior is not quite so crazy as you think. A t-distribution with one degree of freedom has very wide tails. In this with location = -100 and scale = 2.5 you still have a density of > 1e-5 for 0.645 and 0.0112. This is still more than 1/2000 of the maximum density of your prior. This is easily overwhelmed by the likelihood function for your amount of data. BTW the 1/2000 is not intended to create a link to your sample size, i just want to made concrete how wide the tails of your prior are.

Comment: Relevant reference: [A. O'Hagen, 1990. Outliers and credence for location parameter esimation. JASA 85(409), 172-176](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2289540?uid=3739448&uid=2&uid=3737720&uid=4&sid=21101115808171). Short, short version: it's not the absolute value of the prior density *per se* that matters but rather how flat the prior density is in the region of high likelihood, and vice versa.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks, Erik and all. Cyan... thanks especially for the citation.

Comment: Secondary question: Is there any way to figure out how off the prior mean would have to be, given a reasonably wide distribution near the mode? I'm sure there's going to be a mathematically way of doing it. I'd be more interested in simulation/graphical demonstration.