# Queries on the Bayesian method

Tags: bayesian

Currently I am working on a bayesian model framework and have questions related to the philosophy of using such techniques of modeling.

1. How do I know that the prior which I have captured from the experts is valid. There are parameters of the model which has captured a very wide range - say, 10% to 90%. It does not give me comfort, rather, it may show that the expert panel inputs missed out on the clear range. Is there any method out there which may allow me to check this?
2. We do not have enough data to work on, thus, the Bayesian framework. When can we say that Bayesian analysis is not required and the whole analysis/ model can be done using data. Is there any threshold on data availability/ philosophy where it indicates the transition from Bayesian to classical? (I understand that they are techniques from two different school of thought, so Bayesian is used in our case for lack of data)
3. The conjugate prior method for a beta-beta-beta model gives 
   alpha estimate for posterior = a1+a2-1
   beta estimate for posterior = b1+b2-1. 
   the question which haunts me is, how will the effect of a larger data set be captured in the posterior parameters, if this model is being used post the required amount of data is available?

It would be great if someone can answer my questions. If further clarification is required on my thoughts/ questions... please do let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Frankly, I still do not understand what is going on regarding questions 1 and 3. What does for example"There are parameters of the model which has captured a very wide range - say, 10% to 90%. It does not give me comfort, rather, it may show that the expert panel inputs missed out on the clear range" mean? Do you any clear conflict between the prior and data?

Comment: With regards to the 2nd question, there are advantages (and in some cases and applications disadvantages) to a bayesian approach beyond using informative priors. For example, bayesian models works very well if you have to average over hierarchical structures. Usually you don't switch to frequentist methods with more data, you just change to vague and hopefully noninformative priors.

Comment: Regarding question 3, [the answers to this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30387/what-is-the-relationship-between-sample-size-and-the-influence-of-prior-on-poste) should be of interest to you.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your answer on my 2nd query. Looks like I require some research around informative and non-informative priors. :-) On the 1st question, I am facing two types of challenges. 
1st challenge: There is conflict with prior and data. Like, I see the expert opinion to lie between 15 to 50 percent, where as my data captures 3%-12%. (If this is what you ean by "conflict")

Comment: 2nd Challenge: The expert has given a wide range for the parameter X, say, 10% to 90%, and my data (even after I have a fair enough sample for that partcular parameter estimation) gives a value of 12% with a range of 5% to 25%. No way I see this this parameter X go upto 90%.

Comment: Thanks MansT, the answer referenced to was of tremendous help.
Rgds, 
Bik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to test the experts opinion is to look for an independent related study, experiment, or set of data which is very similar to yours. Hopefully some estimated parameters from a similar analysis of those data sources would help you form a similar informative prior to the expert. This is a suggested approach to forming informative priors in the FDA clinical device guidelines section 4.5 (http://www.fda.gov/medicaldevices/deviceregulationandguidance/guidancedocuments/ucm071072.htm ).  Then you could try different priors centered on an estimated value from the study. The first prior may be "optimistic" in the sense that it accommodates the conclusions of the past study, and the experts opinion. The other prior may be "skeptical", in that it accommodates the previous study but it doesn't lend much credit to the experts opinion. Finally do a vague prior which allows a wide range of possibilities and assumes no real information.
   Examine the posterior results using each prior separately. Do they give any different information? If so, then justifying one prior may be very important and help provide useful results. If not then, there may be no utility in making an informative prior, and I would just use the results of a vague prior.

Like Erik said there are some details lacking in your question, but hopefully I helped out.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the insight of the usefulness of using different priors.