# Posterior density problem

Tags: bayesian, posterior, conjugate-prior

I am preparing for an exam and I have stumbled upon this exercise, which I am not certain of.

> a)
> You are given i.i.d. data $x_1, \dots, x_n$ from a continuous distribution with density $\frac{\alpha p^{\alpha}}{x^{\alpha +1}}$ if $x \geq p$ and $0$ if $x \leq p$ and prior $\pi(x)\propto p^{\gamma-1}e^{-\beta p}$ for $\alpha>0, \beta>0, \gamma>0$ given and $x \in (0,\infty)$. Derive the posterior density. b) Is the prior conjugate to the data model? Justify. c) Is there an influence of the prior on the posterior as the sample size goes to infinity? Justify.

My approach to calculating the posterior:
$$p(p|x) = \frac{p(x|p)\cdot\pi(x)}{p(x)}\propto \frac{\alpha p^{\alpha}}{x^{\alpha+1}}\cdot p^{\gamma-1}\cdot e^{-\beta p} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{x\geq p}$$
For point b) I am really not sure - on one hand, the distribution looks very similar, but we also divide by the term with $x$, which confuses me. I'd still say that the prior is conjugate but ti's a guess

For point c) I found a nice answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30387/what-is-the-relationship-between-sample-size-and-the-influence-of-prior-on-poste?newreg=c0e18ae590ae415898c4b2434f5f93e1).

Could someone confirm my solutions and explain point b)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Erm, it is most confusing to use the notation $p$ for both the model parameter and for most densities involved. For instance, using $p(p|x)$ is bad practice. What about rewriting the question with $\rho$ instead of $p$ for the model parameter, $f$ for the sampling density and $\pi$ for the posterior density (common Bayesian practice)? (There is a typo in Bayes' formula, $\pi(x)$ should be $\pi(p)$.)

Comment: Hints: a) the equation only considers $n=1$. For a generic $n$ gather all powers of $p$ and normalise the rhs. b) $x$ is taken as constant in the conditioning, hence division by $x^{\alpha+1}$ should not matter. c) The link provides an intuition about the asymptotic behaviour of the prior, but the rigorous answer involves looking at the limiting distribution of $\theta$ given $x_{1:n}$.